# General solution of $x^{ 2 }\left( y-x\frac { dy }{ dx } \right) =y{ \left( \frac { dy }{ dx } \right) }^{ 2 }$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the differential equation

$${ x }^{ 2 }\left( y-x\dfrac { dy }{ dx }  \right) =y{ \left( \dfrac { dy }{ dx }  \right)  }^{ 2 }.$$

I tried it by first finding $\dfrac { dy }{ dx } $ using quadratic formula but I am getting a complex differential equation
$\dfrac { dy }{ dx } =\dfrac { -{ x }^{ 3 }\pm \sqrt { { { x }^{ 6 }+ }4{ x }^{ 2 }{ y }^{ 2 } }  }{ 2y } $

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi the LHS does look like a $d(\frac{x}{y})$ but the RHS contains the square of the derivative which I am unclear how to proceed with.

Comment: @Tony checking on wolfram alpha, it looks like it's not a pretty trivial question, so I would remove my comment about using d(x/y)

Answer (score 2):

$${ x }^{ 2 }\left( y-x\dfrac { dy }{ dx }  \right) =y{ \left( \dfrac { dy }{ dx }  \right)  }^{ 2 }.$$
Differentiate with respect of the variable $u=x^2$:
$$y-2u\dfrac { dy }{ du }  =4y{ \left( \dfrac { dy }{ du}  \right)  }^{ 2 }.$$
Multiply by $y (y \ne 0)$ both sides ( note $y=0$ is a solution of the DE):
$$y^2-2uy'y  =4y^2{ \left( y'  \right)  }^2$$
$$w=uw' +{w'}^2$$
Where $u=x^2$ and $w=y^2$

This is [Clairaut's differential equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation)
$$y=xy'+f(y')$$
Is the general solution of Clairaut's equation.
$$y=Cx+f(C)$$
So that:
$$w=Cu+f(u)=Cu+C^2$$
$$\boxed {y^2(x)=C(x^2+C)}$$
Is the general solution of the differential equation. You still need to find the singular solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $y\equiv0$ is a solution, we can as well multiply the equation by $y$. Then, with $$z=\frac12y^2+\frac18x^4,$$ we arrive at $$2x^2z=z'^2,$$ after an elementary calculation.
Can you take it from there?

Comment: My knowledge of differential equations is rudimentary, so please consider
this comment in that light.  How do you know that $y\equiv 0$ is a 
solution?  When $y = 0$, LHS is $(-x^3) y'$ and RHS is 0, assuming that
$y'$ is well defined at $y=0$.  Are you assuming here the initial
conditions of $f(0) = 0$, $f(x) \neq 0$ when $x \neq 0$, and $f'(0)$ is
not infinite?

Comment: @user2661923 The solution $y\equiv0$ also satisfies $y^\prime\equiv0$; the $\equiv$ indicates these are true at all $x$.